# JSch issue - Cannot retrieve full command output

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am using JSch to connect to SSH and execute commands. One of the commands gives out a big output. In terminal if you execute the command  you have to press enter to see the entire output. Using JSch I am not able to retrieve the entire output.

When I login using an interactive terminal, the command output stops after filling a screen and waits for <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The code is taken from 
[How to get jsch shell command output in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789245/how-to-get-jsch-shell-command-output-in-string):

```
public class SshConnectionManager {

    private static Session session;
    private static ChannelShell channel;
    private static String username = "";
    private static String password = "";
    private static String hostname = "";


    private static Session getSession(){
        if(session == null || !session.isConnected()){
            session = connect(hostname,username,password);
        }
        return session;
    }

    private static Channel getChannel(){
        if(channel == null || !channel.isConnected()){
            try{
                channel = (ChannelShell)getSession().openChannel("shell");
                channel.connect();

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error while opening channel: "+ e);
            }
        }
        return channel;
    }

    private static Session connect(String hostname, String username, String password){

        JSch jSch = new JSch();

        try {

            session = jSch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
            Properties config = new Properties(); 
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.setPassword(password);

            System.out.println("Connecting SSH to " + hostname + " - Please wait for few seconds... ");
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected!");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("An error occurred while connecting to "+hostname+": "+e);
        }

        return session;

    }

    private static void executeCommands(List<String> commands){

        try{
            Channel channel=getChannel();

            System.out.println("Sending commands...");
            sendCommands(channel, commands);

            readChannelOutput(channel);
            System.out.println("Finished sending commands!");

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("An error ocurred during executeCommands: "+e);
        }
    }

    private static void sendCommands(Channel channel, List<String> commands){

        try{
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());

            out.println("#!/bin/bash");
            for(String command : commands){
                out.println(command);
            }
            out.println("exit");

            out.flush();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error while sending commands: "+ e);
        }

    }

    private static void readChannelOutput(Channel channel){

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try{
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            String line = "";
            while (true){
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in.read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    line = new String(buffer, 0, i);
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                if(line.contains("logout")){
                    break;
                }

                if (channel.isClosed()){
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ee){}
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error while reading channel output: "+ e);
        }

    }

    public static void close(){
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Disconnected channel and session");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
        commands.add("ls -l");

        executeCommands(commands);
        close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally should not use "shell" channel to automate a command execution.

The "shell" channel is intended to implement an interactive shell session.

Hence it requests PTY (pseudo-terminal), which has human-friendly, but machine-unfriendly, side-effects that break your code.

Use "exec" channel instead.

See [Execute a list of commands from an ArrayList using JSch exec in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34825155/850848)

---

If you need or want to use the "shell" channel for some reason (but do not, it will bite you anyway), make sure you call `.setPty(false)` before `.connect`:

```
channel = (ChannelShell)getSession().openChannel("shell");
channel.setPty(false);
channel.connect();
```

---

Side notes:

- The `"#!/bin/bash"` is a pure nonsense. The shell ignores all commands starting with `#` (it's comment). There's no point sending it.
- Do not use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`. See [JSch SFTP security with session.setConfig(“StrictHostKeyChecking”, “no”);](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30178936/850848).

Comment: Hi thanks the solution worked.