# How to run Jsch multiple commands from shell-channel using String input instead of console

Tags: java, jsch

I am writing a program using JSch library, and have to open a `shell` channel and execute few commands that are stored in `String`.
I need to feed the input commands from String variable rather than console.
I have come across a post [Jsch : Command Output unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761400/jsch-command-output-unavailable/25845360#25845360)
In code given, its working fine for commands like `pwd`,`whoami` etc, but its going for a hang when i am trying to do a `sudo -u hiveuser -i`.
Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {   
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        String host = "my.host.server";
        String user = "myLoginId";
        String pswd = "myPASSword";

        Session session=jsch.getSession(user,host, 22);
        session.setPassword(pswd);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications","publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
        OutputStream ops = channel.getOutputStream();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops);
        channel.connect();
        ps.println("sudo -iu hiveuser");
        ps.println(pswd);
        ps.println("hive");
        ps.println("desc table myHiveTable;");
        ps.flush();
        ps.close();

        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        System.out.println("Opening...");

        String jarOutput;
        while ((jarOutput = reader.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(jarOutput);
        reader.close();
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try echoing in the password:

```
echo password | sudo -iu hiveuser --stdin
```